# sql server 2008 create columns using a while

Tags: sql-server, numbers

I need to create about 300 columns for a table and I don't want to to it manually.

How can I do this?
I want to have columns like

```
Bigint1..to..Bigint60
Text1  ..to..Text60
```

and so on.

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'mytbl'))
begin
    create table OBJ_AttributeValues(
    ObjectID numeric(18,0) not null
    );
end
else
begin
    DECLARE @A INT
    set @A = 1;
    WHILE(@A <=60)
    BEGIN
        alter table OBJ_AttributeValues
        add ...............................
        set @A = @A+1;
    END
end
```

What should I write instead of "..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic SQL for that, something like

```
DECLARE @SSQL VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @A INT
set @A = 1;
WHILE(@A <=60)
BEGIN
    SET @SSQL = 'alter table OBJ_AttributeValues add Bigint' + CAST(@A as varchar) + ' bigint'
    EXEC (@SSQL)
    set @A = @A+1;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a good idea, you should take the time to write the sql or just copy-paste the columns from Excel or something like that. You also shouldn't be using the `TEXT` data type, is deprecated and filled with restriction (use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead if you need). That said, here is a way using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @BigintCols NVARCHAR(MAX), @TextCols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @BigintCols = ''
SET @TextCols = ''

SELECT  @BigintCols = @BigintCols + N'Bigint' + CAST(number AS NVARCHAR(2)) + N' BIGINT,',
        @TextCols = @TextCols + N'Text' + CAST(number AS NVARCHAR(2)) + N' TEXT,'
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 60
ORDER BY number

SET @Query = '
CREATE TABLE OBJ_AttributeValues(ObjectID numeric(18,0) not null,'+@BigintCols+
LEFT(@TextCols,LEN(@TextCols)-1)+')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

Oh, you should probably read about [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html%E2%80%8E) first.